# Como definir tamanho de um array de bytes dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, array

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que cria um `arquivo.txt` e salva em uma coluna da minha tabela no banco de dados. O problema está na consulta desse arquivo.

O que acontece, quando quero fazer a consulta tenho que ter um array de bytes com tamanho definido, para receber esses dados do banco que estão em formato de bytes. Porém não estou conseguindo definir esse tamanho dinamicamente.

Cheguei a usar Int32.MaxValue, porém está dando erro de memória.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Segue o código.

```
public static void GetArqTxtBD(int idColumBD, string pstrNomeArqTxt)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = ConexaoBD.CriarConexao())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspCtzTesteSelectArqtxtBd", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idTesteSalvar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idColumBD;

            FileStream fs;                                  // Escreve o BLOB para o arquivo (*.txt).
            BinaryWriter bw;                                // Define um Streams para o objeto 
            int tamanhoBuffer = Int32.MaxValue;             // Tamanho do buffer do BLOB
            byte[] byteSaida = new byte[tamanhoBuffer];     // o buffer BLOB byte[] para ser preenchido com GetBytes.
            long retorno;                                   // Os bytes retornados de GetBytes.
            long inicioIndice = 0;                          // A posicao inicial no BLOB de saida

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Cria o arquivo para tratar a saida dos dados
                    using (fs = new FileStream(pstrNomeArqTxt, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        using (bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                            // Reseta o byte de inicio para o novo BLOB.
                            inicioIndice = 0;

                            // Le os bytes no byteSaida[] e retem o numero de bytes retornados
                            retorno = reader.GetBytes(0, inicioIndice, byteSaida, 0, tamanhoBuffer);

                            // Continua lendo e escrevendo enquanto existir bytes ate completar o tamanho do buffer
                            while (retorno == tamanhoBuffer)
                            {
                                bw.Write(byteSaida);
                                bw.Flush();

                                //Reposiciona o inidice de inicio para o fim ultimo buffer e preenche o buffer
                                inicioIndice += tamanhoBuffer;
                                retorno = reader.GetBytes(0, inicioIndice, byteSaida, 0, tamanhoBuffer);
                            }
                            // Escreve o restante do buffer
                            bw.Write(byteSaida, 0, (int)retorno);
                            bw.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Process.Start(pstrNomeArqTxt);
}
```

Comment: Consegui resolver, porém não sei se seria a melhor forma. O código é o seguinte:     tamanhoBuffer = ((byte[])reader.GetValue(0)).Length;                       
                    byteSaida = new byte[tamanhoBuffer]; No caso agora meu array terá o tamanho do arquivo de texto, e, não ocorrerá estouro de 2gb de memória.

Answer (score 2):

A implementação atual do `System.Array` usar `Int32` para todos os seus contadores internos etc, então o número máximo teórico de elementos é `Int32.MaxValue`.

Mas o .NET framework também tem um limite máximo de tamanho do objeto de 2GB, imposta pela Microsoft CLR.

Uma boa discussão e solução alternativa aqui ...

- [BigArray , ficando em torno do limite de tamanho de matriz 2 GB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/joshwil/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit)

E alguns relacionados, perguntas e respostas aqui...

- [Existe um limite de elementos que poderiam ser armazenados em uma lista?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730821/is-there-a-limit-of-elements-that-could-be-stored-in-a-list/1730836#1730836)
- [Coleção muito grande em .net faz com exceção de falta de memória](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657181/very-large-collection-in-net-causes-out-of-memory-exception/3657189#3657189)
- [qual é o limite máximo de dados em lista no c #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c/3906931#3906931)

Comment: vou olhar esses links que disponibilizou. Obrigado